# Routing in OpenSIPS

Tags: routing, sip, pbx

How to modify under OpenSIPS1.6.4 the default routing to switch the `From:` field in every instance of incoming SIP packets to a predefined string? According to the documentation the `$fd` pseudovariable is read-only.

e.g. from `foo@192.168.1.1` to `bar@192.168.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

note, it have issues/bugs with routing if u triing to rewrite $fu.
in most case it require rewrite via textopts module.

that is becuase acrodinly to RFC sip proxy must NOT change that.

Answer (score 0):

`$fd` references the domain only (everything after the @ in the From field).

You'd need to rewrite the `$fu` variable.